# Использование меток [table], [таблица], [таблицы]. HTML <table>

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки, описание-метки, использование-метки

Редактируя вопрос про HTML `table` столкнулся с дилеммой:

1. Какие метки следует использовать? [table](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), [таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0), [таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b), ещё что-то?
2. Для чего нужна каждая из них? Какова их сфера применения?
3. Может имеет смысл часть из них слить в одну метку? Или хотя бы добавить описания?
4. Имеет ли смысл добавления метки [html-table](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table)?

### UPDATE

Поступило предложение либо их удалить, либо определить им чёткую цель. Мне кажется это конструктивным, потому что у метки должно быть какое-то предназначение и я полагаю, что какое-то одно и задокументированное. А не метка "на все случаи в жизни". Поэтому добавляю к вопросу метку [удаление-метки](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Надо синонимизировать \[таблицы\]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12885/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight имхо, не в ту сторону дубликат.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ В новом вопросе уже приняли решение о синонимизации, так что лучше закрыть старый. Но если что, я не против закрытия в противоположном направлении.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight про [tag:table] решение еще не принято.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## `// Где мой огнемёт?`

1. [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). Возможно, [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).
2. **Они не нужны. Все три.** Метка не имеет одобренного сообществом описания и назначения, а вы затрудняетесь сходу назвать, к чему именно она относится. Таблицы встречаются много где, конкретно в HTML это довольно небольшая по объёму тема. Но встречаются вопросы и [про таблицы в РСУБД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/586096/mysql-join-4-tables-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85), [про `TableWidget` из Qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581091/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-qtablewidget), [даже про `TableLayout` в Андроиде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520157/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-tablelayout-android)! Либо мы определяем этим меткам конкретное значение и контекст, после чего исправляем вопросы где метка не к месту, либо сжигаем метки совсем. Ну, либо забиваем и рекомендуем не использовать, но *никто ведь не послушает*.
3. См. п. 2, имеет смысл их сжечь. Можно слить, но потом сжечь.
4. Не думаю. Уж очень узкая тема, вполне достаточно [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html). Но активно выпиливать эту метку, существуй она, я не стал бы, она всё-таки однозначна и не особо мешает организации вопросов.

Comment: Flip the [table]!

Comment: @Nofate too much pun. Я б скорее ориентировался на "DROP [tag:table]"

Comment: @D-side Почему нет реакции модераторов на этот вопрос, не знаете?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну, вопрос не первостепенной важности, а однозначного ответа от сообщества, я б сказал, ещё не получено, чтобы принимать меры.

Comment: @D-side, сколько плюсиков считаются однозначным ответом от сообщества?) Я готов жечь, я хочу себе редакторский знак и шляпку)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму я б считал более-менее надёжным как минимум 10 и не менее 70%.

Comment: @D-side Вот уже 10, фразу *"не менее 70%"*, если честно, не понял.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov чтобы из общего количества (не суммы) плюсов и минусов было не менее 70% плюсов.

Comment: @D-side Ок, тогда ждём реакции.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov дык уже :)

Comment: @D-side В смысле *"уже"*? Метки не удалили, отказа тоже не последовало. Что поменялось?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov голоса набрали уже какое-то время назад, я сообщил в чат, Утка взял огнемёт и пошёл выжигать метку из вопросов. Чем кончилось, не знаю, видимо, ещё не кончилось.

Comment: @D-side, я чуть пожег и мне надоело, делаю это постепенно) Есть ли способ выжечь метки со всего срауз - мне неведомо

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, надо понимать что выжигание метки - дело ручное и добровольное, производится участниками сообщества) Автоматический способ доступен только разрабам со, и возможно менеджерам сообщества (Николасу в нашем случае). Но на практике им пользвоаться не принято. Подробнее читаем тут: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work. Это довольно старый вопрос, но модеры по-моему до сих пор не могут, пусть они поправят меня если не так)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Хорошо, без проблем. Просто вы сами вызвались:) Как будет время, буду продолжать наше правое дело. Спасибо, что отписали.

Comment: @D-side совместными усилиями с Уткой удалены метки из вопросов. Нужно позвать модератора чтобы он поставил [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, не думаю, статус-завершено и аналоги - они для работы с движком а не контентом сайта) Кроме того это дело такое, его сложно "завершить", сейчас все удалили, через неделю-месяц еще кто-то налепит этих меток

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Именно эти три метки удалены. В случае чего укажем создающему на это вопрос и снесём их ещё раз. Заметьте, что на подобных вопросы уже добавляли метку [meta-tag:статус-завершено]: к примеру. [этот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/52/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [этот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3303/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ок, значт был неправ, что уже добавляли, не видел)

Comment: Метка table снова появилась, и к ней даже пытаются добавить описание. Никто не против повторного сжигания?

Answer (score -2):

1. Таблицы
2. Для вопросов про таблицы
3. Да
4. Нет

Comment: Хорошо, а можете дать более развёрнутый ответ на вопрос №2? Потому что это очевидно, что для вопросов про таблицы. Также по поводу вопроса №3 хочется понять какие именно метки следует объединить. Или добавить описание. И если да, то какое. По поводу вопроса №1 неясно: а почему не таблица или table (по одноимённому тэгу).