# Обязательное описание метки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, создание-метки

Задав [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4249/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-table-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-html-table) и увидев что иногда приходится требовать [удаление-метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)  (а создать новую метку нетяжело) пришла мысль для обязательного описания метки

1. Во избежание случаев, когда какая-либо метка имеет множество целей и является довольно безликой (к примеру метка [таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0) неясно это таблица в HTML, SQL или вообще, к примеру, мне нужно сгенерировать таблицу в Word программно).
2. Позволит значительно лучше понимать необходимость в этой метке, а также насколько верно она используется по назначению.
3. Чтобы участникам было ясно когда её применять.
4. В целом просто чтобы всем было ясно, что же это такое. Для общей образованности и повышения эрудиции.

---

Так как данный вопрос требует изменения в интерфейсе, то задал тот же вопрос на главной [мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289056/mandatory-tag-description).

Comment: Для информации: у нас тут 3600 меток с хвостиком. Но я всеми щупальцами за улучшение качества и количества описаний.

Comment: @Nofate Ничего, во-первых, дорогу осилит идущий. Во-вторых, можно же сделать, чтобы новые метки нельзя было добавлять без описания, а к старым потихоньку добавим.

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Нельзя просто взять и добавить что-то в движок, т.к. это коснется всех сайтов, а в данном случае еще и UI придется рисовать для создания метки. Вам потребуется очень хорошо обосновать это change request, чтобы протолкнуть его к разработчикам (вероятно через Meta.SE).

Comment: Понимаю. Спросил на главной [мете](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289056/mandatory-tag-description).

Comment: А закиньте ссылку в сам вопрос, чтобы не потерялась

Comment: На русскую мету?

Comment: Не, всмысле из комментария поднимите в вопрос.

Comment: И кто будет этот текст (описание метки) создавать? Вопрошающий, который вводит новую метку? Половина будет такой, что лучше бы вообще не было. Устанете отслеживать.

Comment: @avp Так пусть тогда и не создаёт. Если создаётся метка, то пусть и описывается.

Comment: Да почти никто, *озабоченный* ***своим*** *вопросом*, не будет прилагать усилия к хорошему описанию новой метки. А в половине случаев в ее описании будем видеть -- `bla-bla-blf.................`