# Должна ли метка быть однозначной?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Часто встречаюсь с аргументом против удаления метки, что она полезна "в паре" с другими. Я считаю это неправильным и предлагаю такие контраргументы.

1. Общие метки сами по себе бесполезны.
2. Никто не будет покрывать кучу вопросов общей меткой. Например, 50-60% вопросов, допустим меткой [веб-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). Хотя по сути большинство вопросов (или, по крайней мере существенная часть), именно про это. Даже если кто-то возьмётся, считаю, это будет оккупированием одно из пяти мест для более подходящей метки.
3. Вдохновляют задавать слишком общие вопросы, которые в подавляющем большинстве хорошие кандидаты на закрытие или удаление.

---

Предлагаю сжигать подобные метки, а также (если возможно) закрепить подобное положение в правилах. Также разрешить подобные споры будет помогать [обязательное описание метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4260/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Comment: "Общие метки" уточняют область  для которой задан вопрос (и вообще, позволяют вносить логическую иерархию в существующую "плоскую" модель) , поэтому они полезны.