# Вы можете выполнять это действие раз в N секунд

Tags: дефект, правки, удаление-метки

При массовом редактировании вопросов для [удаления меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4252/220571) может всплывать сообщение "Вы можете выполнять это действие раз в 1 секунду", "Вы можете выполнять это действие раз в 2 секунды" или "Вы можете выполнять это действие раз в 3 секунды". Причём я абсолютно уверен, что это точно меньше секунды не занимает (я точно не такой шустрый).

А по-хорошему должен быть задан один конкретный временной интервал, а то это  сейчас выглядит как псевдослучайная величина.

Comment: Смахивает на побочные эффекты от [этого](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3471/178988)...