# Надо синонимизировать [таблицы]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие вот три метки на тему таблиц:

- [таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0) (46 вопросов)
- [таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b) (185 вопросов)
- [table](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) (282 вопроса)

Надо бы их синонимизировать (главная, наверное, - [таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)).

Comment: Насколько много у нас дубликатов меток в единственном/множественном числе? Вы их как-то скриптом находите, или вручную? Я подумал, может, вместо того, чтобы плодить на каждую пару меток отдельный вопрос, лучше бы одним вопросом составить список, совместно проверить его, а затем их кучей синонимизировать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight каждая пара меток обсуждается индивидуально. Лично мне формат "одна группа - один вопрос" удобен.

Comment: @aepot сейчас, насколько я вижу, ничего особо не обсуждается, очевидные синонимы создаются сразу, как модератор видит тему. Я не сомневаюсь, что удобен, но имеет смысл объединить такие случаи, чтобы не захламлять список вопросов на мете однотипными предложениями. На EN SO, например, подобный список создавали: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/8674428

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я их даже особо не ищу. Просто просматриваю список вопросов - вижу подозрительную метку, ищу похожие - и вопрос на Мету ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синонимизировал и объединил [таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0) → [таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b).

Что касается [table](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), то не уверен пока, что его вообще стоит трогать. Так как метка на кириллице понятно, что означает, а вот table может иметь прямое отношение к HTML тегу `<table>`, поэтому давайте пока оставим как есть.

Comment: если имеет отношение к тегу, то это будет в тексте вопроса. А по сути это ведь всё равно таблица. Поэтому, мне кажется, надо тоже в эту кучу её. Дополнительно можно [tag:html-table] создать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ верно, но в этом случае надо руками отсортировать почти 300 вопросов. Без этого я не вижу особого смысла в объединении.

Comment: Имхо, не обязательно. От того, что метка [table] превратится в [таблицы] хуже не станет. Если сейчас она вперемешку, то наиболее рациональным мне видится вариант замены сейчас, чтобы потом уже не продолжалось это безобразие, а вешали на новые [html-table]. Пока не могу представить реальный кейс, что вопрос вообще будет потерян для поиска, если такую замену утвердить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну добей тогда, допиши ответ, я не буду возражать.

Comment: @aepot, а что проще - посмотреть 300 вопросов, или сначала объединить, а потом посмотреть 500 вопросов?

Comment: @Qwertiy проще - не трогать. Но возможно стоит для начала пересечение меток оценить. И узнать, что там большая часть именно html, какая-то часть sql. Конечно, быть может и стоит объединить.

Comment: @Qwertiy проще не смотреть, ни 300, ни 500.